# Unable to access StrongLoop API on a production host - Listening Port is empty

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I setup new StrongLoop Process Manager on new Production Server (Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr) as per http://strong-pm.io/prod/

```
npm install -g strong-pm
sudo sl-pm-install
sudo /sbin/initctl start strong-pm
```

I managed to build and deploy app from my development machine using following commands:

`slc deploy -s appthree http://[productionIP]:8701 ..\scc-1.0.0.tgz`

However, I'm unable to access loopback API created, supposedly at http://[productionIP]:3000 (or 3000+serviceID)

`slc ctl -C http://[productionIP] status` shows deployed app Listening Ports is empty

[image]

http://[productionIP]:8701, http://[productionIP]:8701/explorer/, and http://[productionIP]:8701/api/Services are accessible.

My app server\config.json is

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 3000,
  "remoting": {
    "context": {
      "enableHttpContext": false
    },
    "rest": {
      "normalizeHttpPath": false,
      "xml": false
    },
    "json": {
      "strict": false,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "extended": true,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "cors": false,
    "errorHandler": {
      "disableStackTrace": false
    }
  },
  "legacyExplorer": false
}
```

And package.json is

```
  {
    "name": "scc",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "server/server.js",
    "scripts": {
      "pretest": "jshint ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "compression": "^1.0.3",
      "cors": "^2.5.2",
      "errorhandler": "^1.1.1",
      "loopback": "^2.14.0",
      "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
      "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.19.0",
      "loopback-connector-rethinkdb": "git://github.com/fuwaneko/loopback-connector-rethinkdb",
      "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
    },
    "optionalDependencies": {
      "loopback-explorer": "^1.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "async": "^1.0.0",
      "jshint": "^2.5.6"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "",
      "url": ""
    },
    "description": "scc",
    "bundleDependencies": [
      "compression",
      "cors",
      "errorhandler",
      "loopback",
      "loopback-boot",
      "loopback-connector-rethinkdb",
      "loopback-datasource-juggler",
      "loopback-explorer",
      "serve-favicon"
    ]
  }
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: The `wid` columns in your app status lists is _very_ high, which strongly suggests your app is in a crash/restart loop. You might be able to figure out the cause by looking at the logs with `slc ctl -C xxx log-dump 1`.

Comment: You're right. I missed out installing git, thus the service crashed when it attempts to get loopback-connector-rethinkdb. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Added my comment as an answer so it is easier for people to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the high `wid` values it appears your app is repeatedly crashing and being restarted.

Check the logs with `slc ctl -C <xxx> log-dump 1` to see why and that should help you get up and running.